# Print SlideShow

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

I have a notebook as SlideShow with a cell containing graphics and formatted text as a DockedCell.
Now I want to print the notebook WITH the docked cell, maybe one slide per page.
How could this be done?
I tried also to put the same cell used as docked cell as a header cell. But then the cell is formatted differently (much bigger).